# How to create a line with a label centered above it?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, geometry, labeling

Can anyone help me create a line with a label shown in the picture below?  The line is discontinuous near the middle to accomodate the label. The label is placed on top to avoid the problem when the two points are too close.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
lines[{a1_, a2_}, color_, label_] := Block[{d,l},
d = a2 - a1;
l = Norm[d];
  {Thickness[0.01], color, Line[{a1, a2}]}]

Graphics@lines[{{1, 2}, {3, 5}}, Red]
```

My plan is to make the line segments about 4/10 of the distance between two points from each end as shown in the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The main idea is that a label can be placed at a distance `d` on an circle at angle `rotp` around the point `pt` as defined in the function. The label `l` can itself be rotated at an angle `rotl`.

```
Clear[slope, pt1, pt2, slope, labelAt];

slope[pt1_, pt2_] := ArcTan[Divide @@ Reverse@(pt2 - pt1)]*180/π;

labelAt[pt_, rotp_, d_, l_, rotl_] := Module[{},
  { Rotate[Text[l, pt + FromPolarCoordinates[{d, rotp }]], rotl]}
  ]

pt1 = {1, 5};
pt2 = {3, 4};

Graphics[{
  (* Midpoint *)
  Black, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point@Midpoint[{pt1, pt2}]
  
  (* Label Q1 at pt1 with a red circle *)
  , Red, Circle[pt1, 0.1], 
  labelAt[pt1, 90 Degree + slope[pt1, pt2] Degree, 0.15, "Q1", 
   slope[pt1, pt2] Degree]
  
  (* an orange colored Label Q2 at pt2 with a stylized polygon *)
  , FaceForm[Directive[Green, Opacity[0.2]]], EdgeForm[Red], 
  RegularPolygon[pt2, 0.1, 5]
  , Orange, labelAt[pt2, 60 Degree, 0.2, "Q2", slope[pt1, pt2] Degree]
  
  (* black line stretching 4/5 of the way *)
  , Black
  , Line[{
    Subdivide[pt1, pt2, 5][[1]]
    , Subdivide[pt1, pt2, 5][[3]]
    }]
  
  (* thicker blue line leading up to pt2 *)
  , Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]
  , Line[{
    Subdivide[pt1, pt2, 5][[4]]
    , Subdivide[pt1, pt2, 5][[6]]
    }]
  
  (* label at midpoint, distance of 0.1 normal to line *)
  (* use -90 to move it to the other side *)
  (* change angle and distance to position it anywhere *)
  , Blue, labelAt[Midpoint[{pt1, pt2}]
   , 90 Degree + slope[pt1, pt2] Degree, 0.1
   , Style[
    "slope = " <> ToString@(slope[pt1, pt2] // N) <> "°", Red,
     12]
   , slope[pt1, pt2] Degree]
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {3, 6}}
 ]
```

[image]